# Date format with Salesforce REST API

Tags: rest-api, api, php

I'm retrieving the "LastModifiedDate" attribute of a File through a GET request with the Salesforce REST API but I just can't figure out the date format.

Salesforce's documentation states the date format is ISO8601 but when I do the following in PHP :

```
// The value I retrieve is "2014-11-20T14:23:44.000+0000"
$date = \Datetime::createFromFormat(\Datetime::ISO8601, [value]);
```

PHP throws an error saying it couldn't create a date with this format and this value.

Do you know what is the actual date format used by Salesforce in its REST API ?

Thanks for your answers.

Cheers.

Comment: Docs say *The date and time should be provided in ISO 8601 format: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+hh:mm*. Try changing your time to *2014-11-20T14:23:44.00+00:00* and see if it works

Comment: Hey Novarg, thanks for the answer :) Unfortunately the time is coming directly from Salesforce and that's only once I got it that I'm trying to create a date object with PHP. So even if I change it manually for testing purposes and PHP manages to create a date object, that still doesn't fix my problem since I won't be able to change manually all the date values I receive from Salesforce everytime I ask for a date value with the REST API. Any other idea though ?

Comment: Could this be something you are looking for? http://search.cpan.org/~carlvince/DateTime-Format-Salesforce-0.01_01/lib/DateTime/Format/Salesforce.pm

Comment: Hey Novarg, I think what you've found is the best I can get since there are not a lot of documentation about this strange behavior. At least it confirms that Salesforce actually sends the wrong date format. I'll try to come up with a solution and post it here. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php you can try this

```
<?php
    $value = "2014-11-20T14:23:44.000+0000"; // example value
    $value = substr($value,0,19);
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d?H:i:s', $value);
    print( "TEST<br> ".$value ."<br>" ); 
    print_r( $date );    
?>
```

To respect the timezone, you need a bit more string cutting. It looks like the milliseconds needs to be removed an the offset need a ":" inbetween. Look for the string functions here http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php

Comment: Unfortunately that would make me lose the information about the timezone since you're removing the last "+0000" of the value. Check out the answer I posted and let me know if you feel that's OK :)

Comment: Edited my answer. Would not use regexp here, even if it works. Consider readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the "dirty" solution I've implemented : upon receiving the date, I preg replace the pattern `/\.[\d]{3}/` (removing the milliseconds) and then I'm good to go to create a date from the format ISO8601.

So instead of :

```
// The value I retrieve is "2014-11-20T14:23:44.000+0000"
$date = \Datetime::createFromFormat(\Datetime::ISO8601, [value]);
```

I do :

```
// The value I retrieve is "2014-11-20T14:23:44.000+0000"
$date = \Datetime::createFromFormat(\Datetime::ISO8601, preg_replace('/\.[\d]{3}/', '', [value]);
```

Thanks to Novarg and RichartT for pointing me to the right direction.

I won't be able to accept my own answer right away so if you feel there's a better way to solve this, please don't hesitate and if your solution is better than mine, I'll accept it as the correct one :)

Comment: I believe that you're missing a closed parenthesis in your second code snippet.